# How to add Firebase Performance without Performance Plugin in Android

Tags: android, firebase, chromium, firebase-performance

I am working on Chromium project. I want to add Firebase Performance but Chromium doesn't have file build.gradle level project, so I can't add Performance Plugin.
Can add Firebase Performance without Performance Plugin? Or have another way to add Performance Plugin in Chromium?